# New User Profile Service Application creation Is returning timeout expired error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

Good day,
I am trying to deploy SP site collection from development server to live but noticed I had issues with User Profiles so I deleted and in the process of creating another User Profile Service Application using Powershell, It returned this error 'New-SpProfileServiceApplication : Timeout expired .' as shown in the attached. [image: Error Message]
I've searched and all options don't seem to work. Urgent help needed please.

Comment: Does your server and SQL server meet the minimum specification for SharePoint? The error suggests that it simply isn't able to complete the action in a normal amount of time.

Comment: Yes they do. It's a live server like I said. There are a number of services running on it. The SQL server is a cluster though

Comment: Have you considered giving the user profile service it's own application pool?

Comment: Yes I have. But it returns the same error.

Comment: Is there anything in the ULS logs?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any direction in the uls logs. Or is there another location? I'm checking @ C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS. This is the right path right?

Comment: That is the default location. On a side note, I would definitely store the ULS logs on a different drive for a production environment. If the ULS logs grow too large and they are stored on the C drive, it can cause a lot of problems.

Comment: I get you. I have tried all I can to no avail. All connections seem to be intact. I changed the log files location as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that contributed.
I will drop the solution in case there is someone who needs it.

USER PROFILE SERVICE CREATION TIMEOUT ISSUES:

**STEP 1**: To delete User Profile service Application

1. Get-SPServiceApplication --> This gives a list of service apps
2. Copy the particular id of the app to be deleted
3. `$todel = Get-SPServiceApplication 00a368c9-21d5-4ba4-b03a-fe76c7960bd9`
4. `$todel.Delete()`

**STEP 2***: Get faulty timer jobs that have been orphaned after deleting User Profile Service Application

1. `Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq $null }| select Id` --> This list the id of all orphaned jobs
2. Pick the id's one by one and pass into a variable as it is below(N.B: you can have multiple line, copy and paste at once)

```
$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob d8b33cf4-39c4-49ca-8a02-67d77138f3e1
$FaultyJob.Delete()
$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob  871b7272-ccde-4556-a142-d2c8b7e8223f
$FaultyJob.Delete()$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob  384a4284-e55c-4e48-bb44-2d822f78c751
$FaultyJob.Delete()
$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob  deebdfff-eb31-493d-854e-319ca3f27293
$FaultyJob.Delete()
$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob  fe19f397-1dbf-412b-86bb-cb7e03a33cc2
$FaultyJob.Delete()
$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob 9aea80a1-f921-40b2-8383-90c9ee79fdec
$FaultyJob.Delete()
$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob  5f129a1e-fb18-49ab-8cc6-6a0b480b7c08
$FaultyJob.Delete()
$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob  577f08cb-40bc-4649-8a31-07605e177ab8
$FaultyJob.Delete()
$FaultyJob = Get-SPTimerJob  5f129a1e-fb18-49ab-8cc6-6a0b480b7c08
$FaultyJob.Delete()
```

**STEP 3**:

1. Check all servers in the farm to confirm they are all up and running
2. Start all services on the servers. To start, Central Administration > Manage services on this server

**STEP 4**

1. Launch the configuration wizard.

Voila! you have the user profile service application created.